# Unable to send Https requests (Running Tomcat 8.5 in SSLv3)

Tags: java, tomcat

I am setting SSLv3 in tomcat v8.5 server.xml file using Nio Protocol and using Java 1.8. When i hit the request from IE ,i am getting response, but through a java code i am getting exception as below.

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

I updated the development.properties which is in users/db8/Appdata/LocalLow/sun/java/deployment/deployment.properties (deployment.security.SSLv3=true) and i removed SSLv3 from java.security file. I enabled sslv3 in Internet Explorer.

```
    server.xml 
    <Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
    port="8443" maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true" 
    SSLEnabled="true" keystoreFile="keystore.jks" keystorePass="changeit" 
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="SSLv3" />

java code

import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

public class JavaHttpsExample
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String certificatesTrustStorePath = "keystore.jks";
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",
    certificatesTrustStorePath);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3");
    System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.protocols", "SSLv3");
    String httpsURL = "https://ip:8443/test/getData";
    URL myUrl = new URL(httpsURL);
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)myUrl.openConnection();
    try{       
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
    br.close();
    } catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("exxception"+e);
    }    
    }
    }
```

I am adding the result after updating debug = all

Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(0) called
%% No cached client session
update handshake state: client_hello[1]
upcoming handshake states: server_hello[2]
*** ClientHello, SSLv3
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1547297410 bytes = { 170, 53, 106, 27, 73, 55, 4, 39, 195, 152, 66, 1, 124, 244, 6, 114, 106, 181, 46, 183, 184, 202, 56, 105, 225, 158, 210, 195 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]

---

main, WRITE: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 107
main, READ: SSLv3 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
exxceptionjavax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Comment: Run your application with the option `-Djavax.net.debug=all` , you can get a clue for why the ssl handshake fails. Also instead of using `System.getProperty()` provide all the ssl config. details in the java command line.

Comment: @RameshSubramanian I have added the result to my question after updating debug = all.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your server supports TLS Cipher Suites , but your trying with `SSLv3`. Can you run your program with `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` as suggested by the link https://dzone.com/articles/troubleshooting-javaxnetsslsslhandshakeexception-r which explains how to troubleshoot SSL Handshake failures.